# Relation between steps and turns in a simple symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, combinatorics, martingales, expected-value, random-walk

Let $S_0 = 0, S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n$, $n\ge 1$, be a simple symmetric random walk, i.e. $X_i$, $i\ge 1$, are iid random variables with $\mathrm P(X_i = 1) = \mathrm P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$. Denote $\tau = \inf\{n\ge 1: S_n = 0\}$ the time of steps the random walker makes before returning to zero, and let also $\sigma = \#\{1\le k\le \tau-1: X_k X_{k+1} = -1\}$ be the number of turns the walker made.

> Is it true that
>   $$
> \mathrm{E} [\tau - 2\sigma] = 1?\tag{1}
> $$

The problem here is that $\mathrm{E} [\tau] = \mathrm{E} [\sigma] = \infty$.

Here are some ideas why $(1)$ may be true:

1. For any $x\in \mathbb Z$, denote $\tau(x) = \#\{0\le k\le \tau-1: S_k = x \}$ the number of steps made from $x$ and $\sigma(x) = \#\{1\le k\le \tau-1: S_k = x, X_k X_{k+1} = -1\}$ the number of turns made in $x$, $\alpha(x) = \tau(x) - 2\sigma(x)$. Then, $\alpha(0) = 1$, and it is easy to show that $\mathrm{E} [\alpha(x)] = 0$, $x\neq 0$. However, despite that $\tau - 2\sigma = \sum_{x\in \mathbb Z} \alpha(x)$, this does not immediately imply $(1)$: something is needed to swap the sum and expectation signs.
2. Denote $\sigma_n = \#\{1\le k\le n-1: X_k X_{k+1} = -1\}$, the number of turns before moment $n\ge 1$ and let $M_n = n - 2\sigma_n$. Then, $M_n$ is a martingale (actually, a simple symmetric random walk) starting from $M_1 = 1$, and $\tau - 2\sigma = M_\tau$. But this also does not imply $(1)$.

There are some related approaches, including certain direct enumeration, which confirm $(1)$ but lack rigor.

In order to validate these arguments, it suffices to prove that
$$
\mathrm{E} [|\tau - 2\sigma|]<\infty.
$$

---

Edit: the symmetry is false. Indeed, $\mathrm{P}(\tau-2\sigma=0) > \mathrm{P}(\tau=2) =1/2$.

Unfortunately, I can't edit the bounty description.

Comment: Are you sure the expectation exists? The expectation of the positive part of $\tau-2\sigma$ should be roughly $\sum_n\sqrt nC_n4^{-n}$, which diverges. If the correlation between the number of turns and the proximity to the origin is really so strong as to make that expectation finite, it seems unlikely that you can show this with a nice general argument without the enumeration. Could you show how you do it with the enumeration?

Comment: @joriki, I'm not completely sure, actually.

Comment: @joriki, the direct counting I mentioned uses some double summation, so is also flawed. I also ran some simulations - it seems that the expectation is finite (with $\mathrm{E} [|\tau - 2\sigma|] \approx 5$), and the probabilities decay like $x^{-1.1}$ (so it is borderline).

Comment: I also did some simulations and was surprised how small the expectation seemed to be – I didn't even get up to $5$ (but didn't put much effort into optimizing the simulation).

Comment: @zhoraster okay thanks. so it just suffices to get a concentration inequality for $|\sigma(x)-m|$ for $x \in \Sigma_{m,m}^*$. maybe it could follow from some general concentration inequality though seems unlikely.

Comment: It is interesting that my Matlab simulation gives results different from Python. The distribution does not seem to be symmetric (and it is obviously not, see the updated question). Maybe the reason is a larger number of samples (100000). The tail exponent is also smaller (around 1.07). So the true tail exponent may be equal to 1, which means that proving or disproving integrability can be difficult.

Comment: I have a potentially silly question: Does the law of total expectation still hold here?  I.e. can we calculate $P(\tau = t)$ and $E[\sigma \mid \tau = t]$ and then use $E[\tau - 2\sigma] = \sum_t P(\tau=t) E[t - 2\sigma \mid \tau = t]$?  I would guess $E[\sigma \mid \tau = t]$ is a function of $t$, but it cannot be $\infty$.  So shouldn't everything in that equation be well defined?  Or does the law of total expectation only works if the expectation exists to begin with?

Comment: @antkam, this is precisely the point. There is a deleted answer, which uses this idea of total expectation. However, it is not rigorous, since one has to show the integrability.

Comment: @zhoraster - thanks for your reply.  I read the wikipedia article in more detail.  It does say "if $X$ is a random variable whose expected value $E[X]$ is defined" then the law applies.  I never knew this restriction before.  Very interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation does not exist (i.e., $E|2\sigma-\tau|=+\infty$). To see it, condition upon $\tau=n$ (an event of probability about $n^{-3/2}$). Fix now a very small $\alpha>0$ and consider the sequence $S_{4k}$, $k<n/4$.

*Claim* Typically there are at least $\alpha n$ values of $k$ with $S_{4k}=S_{4(k+1)}$ ("level" intervals of length $4$).

*Proof* The total number of admissible paths is about $2^nn^{-3/2}$. Consider all paths in which the condition in the claim is violated. Then we have at least $\frac n4-\alpha n$ pieces of length $4$ that cannot be "level", so the total number of such paths is at most ${n/4\choose \alpha n}10^{n/4-\alpha n}16^{\alpha n}$, which gives a $2^{-cn}$ reduction over the trivial bound $2^n$ if $\alpha>0$ is small enough.

Now consider the "good part" of the probability space and condition upon the values of $S_{4k}$. Then pick up $\frac\alpha 2 n$ separated "level" intervals of length $4$ and condition upon all values $S_m$ except the ones inside those intervals. Then the contributions of those intervals to the total number of turns become independent integer-valued bounded non-constant random variables, so their sum has a constant probability to deviate from any given number by $c\sqrt{\alpha n}$, whence $E[1_{\tau=n}|2\sigma-\tau|]\ge c/n$, so the series diverges.

Comment: Brilliant idea, thanks!